# Stationarity/ADF vs. KPSS Test

Tags: r, time-series

dataset is a time series of index values from 2015 to 2020.
i would like to do see if arima is an adequate forecasting tool for this index.

in a first step i am trying to figure out whether my data is stationary or needs transformation.

looking at the plot i see no seasonality and a constant mean over time, however, variance is changing over time. am i right with this assessment?

[image]

adf test returns p-value of 0.1855 and kpss test shows p-value of 0.1, hence according to adf test time series is not stationary but according to kpss it is stationary.

i have also looked into transormation such as differencing & log returns but as a result data appears to become just white noise (auto arima returns 0,0,0)

can i continue to work with the raw index data without transformation even though adf test is not significant?